# Is there any way to update a specific index from the array in Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way to update a specific index from the array in Firebase/firestore?

```
 export const editComment = (comment) => {
 return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore }) => {
    const firestore = getFirestore();

    firestore.collection('topics').doc(comment.topicId).update({

     comments:  <--- this is array of objects


    }).then(() => {
      dispatch({ type: 'EDIT_COMMENT' })
    }).catch((error) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'EDIT_COMMENT_ERROR', error})
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, you can't. You need to get data and then merge and update it.

Comment: Can you steer me how? i did something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53999186/react-firestore-update-value-in-object-in-nested-array  but it only works at the first update, when i trying second time i getting error

Comment: You should create another collection inside the doc topicId. It is better than create an array or object inside a doc When the data getting bigger

Comment: all my components are based on this comments array so i need to rewritte whole code and add new collection instead of this array? why there is no solution for that simple and fundamentail update action, god...

Comment: i created subsollection but when i getting data through mapStateToProps in react from firestore i only see normal data without created subcollection inside collection, any help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53999186/update-value-in-object-in-nested-array-in-react-firestore/54039820#54039820 here how i did update which works how i wanted

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Is there any way to update a specific index from the array in Firestore?

No, there is not! This is not possible because if you want to perform an update, you need to know the index of that particular element. When talking about Cloud Firestore arrays, the things are different that you might think.

Because we are creating apps that can be used in a multi user environment, try to think what might happen if a user wants to edit a value at index 0, some other user wants to delete the value at index 0 and in the same time some other user might want to add another item at index 0. For sure, you'll end up having very different results and why not, get even array out of bounds exception. So Firestore actions with arrays are a little bit different. So you cannot perform actions like, insert, update or delete at a specific index.

If those two methods do not help you enough, you should get the entire document, get the array, modify it and add it back to the database.

Comment: so i did it and update only works at first time, at second i am getting error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53999186/update-value-in-object-in-nested-array-in-react-firestore

Comment: "get the entire document, get the array, modify it and add it back to the database" Remember to do that in a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions), otherwise you might end up overwriting the change made by another client.

Answer (score 4):

for me, I'm using firebase SDK for flutter, and nodeJS env. for cloud functions,, and I discovered the below solution.

this is a little bit of a hacky workaround

maybe we can save the list in a form of map not an array,, by using the array indexes as key strings to the sub maps

so you have structured the data like this in cloud fire store

```
key1: "value1" --> string
key2:          --> map
 > "0": {subKey1: "subValue1", subKey2: "subValue2"}
 > "1": {subKey3: "subValue3", subKey4: "subValue4"}
 > "2": {subKey5: "subValue5", subKey6: "subValue6"}
```

for example : if you want to update the subValue4, you may do this

```
await docReference.update({key2.1.subKey4: "theNewValueHere"});
```

and this ends up updating that document in cloud firestore to a document that looks like this

```
key1: "value1" --> string
key2:          --> map
 > "0": {subKey1: "subValue1", subKey2: "subValue2"}
 > "1": {subKey3: "subValue3", subKey4: "theNewValueHere"}
 > "2": {subKey5: "subValue5", subKey6: "subValue6"}
```

if you notice in firebase,, it updates the entire field `key2` in this operation,, but gave you an easier access to update that index..

My problem is that I have to restructure all fields having list of maps to become maps within a map to have that access

And I will not do that,, will not refactor my entire db to do that,, I retrieve the entire doc,, (costs 1 read) modify at client and update the entire doc again (1 write)

I don't like it, but maybe someday I would use it

Answer (score 3):

Turn the array into it's own separate document and update the field in there. That's what I did. I had to restructure my database a bit in order to do so.