# How to Remove Arrays of Element in Firebase Cloud Firestore using Ionic 4

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

In My Cloud `Firestore` database structure looks like this. Now, I'd like to delete index positions based on `Index 0`, `Index 1` like this.

```
const arrayLikedImagesRef = {imageurl: image, isliked: true};
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  const deleteRef = db.collection('userdata').doc(`${phno}`);
  deleteRef.update({
    likedimages: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(arrayLikedImagesRef)
  });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `FieldValue` to remove array items by index.  Instead, you could use a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to remove the array items.  Using a transaction ensures you are actually writing back the exact array you expect, and can deal with other writers.

For example (the reference I use here is arbitrary, of course, you would need to provide the correct reference):

```js
db.runTransaction(t => {
  const ref = db.collection('arrayremove').doc('targetdoc');

  return t.get(ref).then(doc => {
    const arraydata = doc.data().likedimages;

    // It is at this point that you need to decide which index
    // to remove -- to ensure you get the right item.
    const removeThisIndex = 2;

    arraydata.splice(removeThisIndex, 1);
    t.update(ref, {likedimages: arraydata});
  });
});
```

Of course, as noted in the above code, you can only be sure you are about to delete the correct index when you are actually inside the transaction itself -- otherwise the array you fetch might not line up with the array data that you originally selected the index at.  So be careful!

---

That said, you might be asking what to do given that `FieldValue.arrayRemove` doesn't support nested arrays (so you can't pass it multiple maps to remove).  In that case, you just want a variant of the above that actually checks values (this example only works with a single value and a fixed object type, but you could easily modify it to be more generic):

```js
const db = firebase.firestore();
const imageToRemove = {isliked: true, imageurl: "url1"};

db.runTransaction(t => {
  const ref = db.collection('arrayremove').doc('byvaluedoc');
  return t.get(ref).then(doc => {
    const arraydata = doc.data().likedimages;
    const outputArray = []
    arraydata.forEach(item => {
      if (!(item.isliked == imageToRemove.isliked &&
            item.imageurl == imageToRemove.imageurl)) {
           outputArray.push(item);
          }
    });
    t.update(ref, {likedimages: outputArray});
  });
});
```

(I do note that in your code you are using a raw boolean, but the database has the `isliked` items as strings.  I tested the above code and it appears to work despite that, but it'd be better to be consistent in your use of types).

Comment: Thank You So much you saved my life, From past One week I'm trying to solve this but I can't Thanks for the Help.

Answer (score 2):

As [explained here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/better-arrays-in-cloud-firestore.html), “bad things can happen when trying to update or delete array elements at specific indexes”. This is why the [Firestore official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) indicates that the `arrayRemove()` function will take elements (strings) as arguments, but not indexes.

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54026098/5921021), if you prefer using indexes then you should get the entire document, get the array, modify it and add it back to the database.