# Updating a single value in firebase Doc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

first time using firebase, i'm creating a blog, when i create a post i'm creating it as:

```
  const postCollection = collection(database, "posts");

  const submitPost = async () => {
    await addDoc(postCollection, {
      title,
      body,
      comments: [],
      liked: false,
      user: { name: auth.currentUser.displayName, id: auth.currentUser.uid },
    });
  };
```

Below each post i have a comment section, but i'm a bit confused about adding the comments.

I tried this:

```
const addComment = async (id) => {
    const targetPost = doc(database, "posts", id);
    await setDoc(targetPost, { ...targetPost, comments: [comment] });
  };
```

But it didn't work.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a post already exists then you can use `updateDoc()` to update specific fields in that document instead of `setDoc()` that will overwrite the document if exists. Since 'comments' is an array, you can use [`arrayUnion()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) to push new comments to your posts as shown below:

```
import { doc, updateDoc, arrayUnion } from "firebase/firestore";

const addComment = async (id) => {
  const targetPost = doc(database, "posts", id);

  await updateDoc(targetPost, {
    comments: arrayUnion(comment)
  });
};
```

Do not that if you need to update a specific comment then you'll have to read the whole post document, update comments array manually and then write the whole comments array back:

```
import { doc, getDoc, updateDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

const addComment = async (id) => {
  const targetPost = doc(database, "posts", id);
  
  const snapshot = await getDoc(targetPost)

  await updateDoc(targetPost, {
    comments: [...snapshot.data().comments, comment]
  });
};
```

Also checkout: [Is there any way to update a specific index from the array in Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54004272/13130697)

For deleting a specific comment, you can use `arrayRemove()` if you know the exact `comment` object.

Comment: The second one is if i want to update some specific comment?

Comment: @JoséCarlos yes, like there's no direct `arrayUpdate()`. Alternatively you can also store comments in a sub-collection so you can update a comment by ID or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Updating documents in Firebase Firestore in React js

----------------import line----------
import { collection, doc, getDocs, setDoc, updateDoc } from 'firebase/firestore'

```
  await updateDoc(doc(db, "Requests", id), {
  fieldName: newValue //field which you have to update
})
```

just this is simple