# how can i add value to specific index in firstore ListField value

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following list field in Firestore.

[image]

Now, I need to place value in `seetsList[2]`.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Rooms').doc(widget.roomId).update({
   'seetsList': FieldValue.arrayUnion(?????????????????)
 });
```

Note: my listValue is always fixed with 5 index and peer index it has default value `0`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can [update an element that exists in an array by its index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54004272/is-there-any-way-to-update-a-specific-index-from-the-array-in-firestore/54026098#54026098). This means you’ll need to:

- Read the content of the array into your application code.
- Update the element in the array using the desired index.
- Write the entire array back to Firestore.

This [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-update-an-array-of-objects-in-firestore-cdb611a56073) might also help.